# Подсчет объектов с группировкой по статусу на указанную дату

Tags: python, алгоритм, django, статистика

Есть журнал, фиксирующий изменение статуса. Пример:

<kbd>`1 мая`</kbd>    <kbd>`Имя1`</kbd>    <kbd>`Назначен`</kbd>  
<kbd>`1 мая`</kbd>    <kbd>`Имя2`</kbd>    <kbd>`Назначен`</kbd>  
<kbd>`1 мая`</kbd>    <kbd>`Имя1`</kbd>    <kbd>`Взят`</kbd>      
<kbd>`2 мая`</kbd>    <kbd>`Имя1`</kbd>    <kbd>`Сдан`</kbd>      
<kbd>`3 мая`</kbd>    <kbd>`Имя2`</kbd>    <kbd>`Взят`</kbd>      
Как правильней подсчитывать с разбивкой по дням, сколько Имён в каком статусе, отличном от стартового, на этот день?
Например результат подсчёта в нашей ситуации:
**1 мая:**
 Назначено: 1
Взято: 1
**2 мая:**
 Назначено: 1
**3 мая:**
 Взято: 1

Comment: Тег `django` и внешний вид задачи "намекают", что данные как-то "введены в компьютер" ? Есть подозрение, что они при вводе попадают в какую-то БД, вот на ней операции и надо проводить. Но хорошо бы Вы уточнили, в каком виде журнал, кроме как "на картинке".

Comment: посмотрите в сторону библиотеки `django-reversion`, это контроль версий и изменений для моделей

Comment: Да, вы правы. Данные хранятся в БД и описаны в проекте Django как модель.

Answer (score 0):

В Pandas есть замечательная функция groupby, помогающая решить вашу задачу. Примерно так

```
df.groupby(["Date","Status"]).count()
```

Что такое "начальный статус" у вас непонятно. Например, почему 1 мая для одного человека начальный статус учтен в результате, а для другого - нет. Откуда 2 мая взялось "Назначен" и пр.  Но тут уже вам, наверное, придется логику дописывать самостоятельно.

Comment: Нет, автор не этого хочет. У него статус меняется Назначен > Взят > Сдан, то есть в один день человек может получить назначение, в какой-то из последующих - принять его, а в третий день - сдать. Соответственно, нужно отслеживать сохранение статуса между днями.

Comment: На 1 мая его актуальный статус был "Взят". Поэтому именно он. Xander верно заметил.